# Turn off all fields except 1 in a pivot Table , Refer to Pivot table by name

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have the following code, where I am  trying to loop through and set the pivot table filter to one specific value. I found it on a prior stack exchange post.

I am having an error when trying to refer to the pivot table by name. I have tried a few methods and I seem to be a bit stuck here.

```
   Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim pi As PivotItem
    

For i = 2 To Direct_Groups.Count
       
            y = Direct_Groups(i).Value
                           
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            Set pt = wb.PivotTables("Direct1")
            
            For Each pi In _
                pt.PivotFields("Group Code").PivotItems
                    Select Case pi.Name
                    Case Is = y
                    pi.Visible = True
                    Case Else
                    pi.Visible = False
                    End Select
                    
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
                Application.ScreenUpdating = True
                Next pi
            ws_Port1.Range("B3:F43").Copy
            ws_Staging.Range(ws_Staging.Cells(46, 1 + (i - 1) * 6), ws_Staging.Cells(86, 1 + (i - 1) * 6)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

I keep getting a runtime error '1004' : Application-defined or object-defined error. On the line

```
 Set pt = wb.PivotTables("Direct1")
```

Comment: Always helps to specify the exact line where the error occurs.  `“Direct1”` do you have those "smart quotes" in your actual code?  VBA will see them as just another character, so you need to replace with regular straight quotes.

Comment: Tim I just updated my question to show where the error occurs.  In the code I use " " as the quotes. When I change " to ' it errors out.

Comment: No, "" is fine.  Single quotes will not work.

Comment: You have `Dim pt As PivotField` should be `Dim pt As PivotTable`

Comment: I changed that in my code. I still get the same error.

Comment: Then it seems like there's no pivottable with that name?  Where is `wb` set?

Comment: Pivottables is a property of a worksheet, not a workbook.

Comment: When I change it work worksheets rather than workbook it seems to run. I guess this was the issue.... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was that "Pivottables is a property of a worksheet, not a workbook"

I had

`wb.PivotTables("Direct1")`

when it should have been

`ws.PivotTables("Direct1")`

where ws  is the name of the sheet the pivot table is on.

Comment: I did check that...   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.pivottables

Comment: On testing...   `Dim pts as PivotTables: Set pts = ThisWorkbook.PivotTables` runs without error, but `pts.Count` is zero  (with one pivot table in the workbook)   Description for this proerty is "Returns an object that represents a collection of all the PivotTable reports on a worksheet. Read-only."  Looks like an error in the docs?

Comment: Interesting.... I am able run through the code when I change to worksheet instead of workbook but now I get a new error. It fails on the pi.visible command. Says it cannot access Visible property.

Comment: You must have at least one item visible, so possibly it's erroring when you try to hide the last visible item.  First make the one item visible, then loop and hide the rest.